# is there anyways to insert array_combined into database?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$fname=array("Peter","Ben","Joe");
$age=array("35","37","43");
$c=array_combine($fname,$age);
print_r($c);
?>
```

after this i need to insert $fname and $age into database using mysqli
but right now, i lost the path to do into database.

my database have:

1- customer (name, age)

can someone help me to solve this problem which is to insert array ($c) into database which insert to their attribute

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. You need to show us what you actually tried, and give us a proper problem description along with it.

Answer (score 1):

With [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) you can do this way to insert record on database's `customer` table from your existing array i.e `$c`,

```
$fname = array("Peter","Ben","Joe");
$age = array("35","37","43");
$c = array_combine($fname,$age);
$query = "INSERT INTO `customer` (`fname`, `age`) VALUES (:fname, :age);";

foreach($c as $fname=>$age) {
   $stmt->execute(array(':fname' => $fname, ':age' => $age));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_encode() to insert JSON in the database and then when you retrieve it use json_decode() to turn it back to an array.

```
$fname = array("Peter","Ben","Joe");
$age = array("35","37","43");
$c = array_combine($fname,$age);
$json = json_encode($c);
```

Comment: How? i never used json before.i tried to google it and i still can't see the answer. can u show the path for me?